# How can I access infrared camera on iPhone 14 Pro?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, infrared

If my knowledge is right, iPhone 14 Pro, and probably others, have IR camera both at front and back. Is there a way to access these cameras? I would like to see if they could be used in big to get typical grey pictures or to see through some plastic and see electronic components inside like it was/is possible with some other phone/phones like OnePlus 8.